# How to type "@" symbol in Russian keyboard layout?

Tags: узус

Does a Russian keyboard layout support the "@" symbol? I had to switch to an English keyboard to type "@".

Comment: This is not topic about Russian language. Answers provided will be converted to comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We do not use it in the Russian layout, as all the email addresses are typed in Latin letters.

Comment: There are Cyrillic domains now, so there are can be e-mails with Cyrillic letters.

Answer (score 6):

The input method for @, working independently of keyboard layout: **Alt + 64**.

Comment: a single relevant answer

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка technically, it is not. Alt+numeric symbol entering was there far before "keyboard layout" as a term cam to IBM PC, and even today it is explicitly outside of layouts realms, anchored directly in Unicode codepoints "table". Alt-numeric is a gate you can use to dive out of layouts - both their comforts and their confines. The only technically correct answer would be that Russian "typewriter" layout used by Windows by default does not have that symbol. Assuming topicstarter meant that layout among many different Russian layouts out there. If to put practicality first, all answers ok

Comment: @Arioch having to switch to another layout which one might not be even using regularly isn't so practical, this answer here relieves from such a need

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка Look, we can describe practicality and we can describe formal correctness, but not both. I disagree on both points, but do not want to mix them. You said all other answers were "irrelevant" - that did not mean they were less practical or less handy, that meant they were incorrect by formal criteria. But by those very same criteria this answer is equally irrelevant. What about practicality, I can have a long comment on this aspect too, including yet more potential "answers", but would prefer not to.

Comment: @Arioch they were, given my understanding of the question, i would think that what the OP really wished to know is how to type the symbol while using Russian layout, knowing that Russian layout lacks the symbol doesn't have any practicality for the OP, especially in view of the fact that he himself already kind of knew it wasn't there

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка then copying the needed symbol out of other text or out of `charmap.exe` standard app is much more practical thing, that memorizing 127 characters of low ASCII (less so -  hundreds millions characters of modern Unicode). Sure, i know this specific thing, because @ goes immediately before capital ABCD...sequence and it starts at the round number ( 64 is 1000000 binary ). But i would never call that a practical solution for any average person. Nor do i remember most other ASCII codes. It is both NOT practical and OUTSIDE the scope of layouts.

Comment: @Arioch indeed advice of copying it out of the Character Map would fit the bill of practical answer for me as well

Answer (score 2):

It is not present in standard PC or Mac Russian keyboard layout, as it is only used in Latin-based e-mail addresses.

However, **mobile devices keyboards sometimes have it**. 
For example, iOS Russian keyboard has the “@“ symbol on “ф” key.